# Rails 3: named parameter routes break link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-routes

I'm trying to create a Rails app that divides the users by groups and sub-groups and offers a customized site to each sub-group. I figured the easiest way to do that was to create scope with named parameters:

```
scope ":group/:subgroup/" do
devise_for :users
    resources :users
end
```

"rake routes" then produces this:

```
       users GET    /:group/:subgroup/users(.:format)             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
             POST   /:group/:subgroup/users(.:format)             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
    new_user GET    /:group/:subgroup/users/new(.:format)         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
   edit_user GET    /:group/:subgroup/users/:id/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
        user GET    /:group/:subgroup/users/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
             PUT    /:group/:subgroup/users/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
             DELETE /:group/:subgroup/users/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

It works perfectly--except when I to use link_to:

```
link_to current_user.name, current_user
```

Then it throws this error

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Users#index 
Showing C:/Rails/MyApp/app/views/users/_my_list.html.haml where line #8 raised: 
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :group=>#<User id: 7, email: "username@domain.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$GdZeC0b4VaNxdsDXP...", password_salt: "$2a$sj$88gm0nttYE.7a4IHi.BNO", reset_password_token: nil, remember_token: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 86, current_sign_in_at: "2011-08-05 17:18:19", last_sign_in_at: "2011-08-05 00:14:26", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2010-12-09 23:08:54", confirmation_sent_at: "2010-12-09 23:08:36", failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: "2010-12-09 23:08:36", updated_at: "2011-08-05 17:18:19", name: "UserOne">}
```

Line #8, of course, is where I tried to use link_to. My guess is that link_to is ignoring the scope, which accounts for current_user getting stuffed into the :group parameter. Is there a way to keep this from happening, or am I going about this whole issue totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `resource :users` is inside the scope, so you don't have the `/users/:id` route.

You could try this:

```
scope ":group/:subgroup/" do
  devise_for :users
end
resources :users
```

I'm not sure if the `scope` has a `shallow => true` option (I think it does and you should probably use it).

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can't reach an user without passing in a group and a subgroup. Reading your error it's possible to understand that rails is trying to convert your current_user to the group.